# Где и как можно использовать конструктор контроллера в Ларавел?

Tags: php, laravel

Где и как можно использовать конструктор контроллера в Ларавел? Приведите пример

Comment: не знаком с ларавел, но сдается мне, что контроллер всегда инициализируется фреймворком, и вам вообще никогда не потребуется использовать (вызывать) конструктор контроллера, разве что переписать его с какой то целью.

Comment: А мне сдается, что в контроллер можно заинжектить какие-нибудь нужные сервисы через конструктор. По крайней мере в симфони так можно. Может и в ларке так можно.